# how to intern a dynamically-created String in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, optimization

I'm trying a generate some template based Strings:

```rust
let username;//unknown at compile time
let template = "(|$|)"; //might be anything

let st = template.replace('$', username);

//do something with st
```

this code is going to be executed in each iteration of an `egui` app, so its really inefficient without caching.

but I'm wondering how can I intern the `st` here? if I just pass it to some intern library and get a result back its not going to have any effect because I'm still creating a new string with `replace` here.

is it even possible to do this or I just have to cache the template itself and then somehow use a `HashMap` of username with the cached result?

Comment: I don't understand how you use the word "intern". Can you explain what you mean with that? Do you mean "inline" at compile-time?

Comment: @maxy [String interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is a common concept when handling a large number of strings.

Comment: @maxy in simple terms, caching strings

Comment: You can keep a mapping `Arc<str> -> Arc<str>` of original to replaced strings. Then if the string is already cached you can skip the replacement.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman problem is that I dont know the combination to cache them until I actually combine them

Comment: You can lookup for the string, and if it does not exist replace and cache it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman can you explain more?

Comment: `if let Some(replaced) = mapping.get(&template) { return replaced; } else { let replaced = Arc::new(template.replace('$', username)); mapping.insert(template, Arc::clone(&replaced)); return replaced; }`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman template could not be the key beqvuse there could be multiple usernames with the same template otherwise you would just have a static string

Comment: So make it `(template, username)`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman hmm could be, but how can a tuple be the key, the Eq, ParticalEq  traits are not implemented for them, are they?

Comment: They are (as long as the elements are).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried this but I realized that I cant use Arc due to template being modified at the runtime so cant move it, and using another wrapper like `Mutex` or `RwLock` would be overkill and just consume much more memory than it saves at the first place,

Comment: A mutex, at least one based on futex is only 5 bytes larger than T it is wrapping, not counting whatever padding may occur.

Comment: @IvanC well im on windows so mutex would be more expensive, ig